# Prefab is not direct copy of original

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer and we did all the movement tweaking in a sample scene, so we figured we could make a prefab of the player and just drag it into each other scene when we're designing the levels. But for some reason, the prefab jumps significantly higher than the original and I can't figure out why. As far as I can tell, prefabs should always be an exact duplicate right?

Comment: You are right prefabs basically means having a Single Reference. It should behave similarly. Might be some Physics Material with different bounciness values is affecting the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know public references are easily messed up when using them in a prefab. Have you tried looking through them if you have any? Also anything you set in a serialized field but not in the script itself might have changed as well.

Comment: You were right: some of the public references got messed up in the prefab for some reason. I put the prefab into the scene, deleted one of the scripts and re-added it with the same values, and it worked perfectly. I then applied those changes to the prefab and now the prefab works perfectly. Thank you!!